# Including multiple views inside main view in sencha

Tags: javascript, iphone, model-view-controller, mobile, extjs

I need to make an appication where there are seperate modules like user, category. I want to make seperate views for all those and then finally want to call in the main view. I am new to sencha . How to do this?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    appFolder: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                   //need to replace this with app.views.userPage,how??????????
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Users',
                    html : 'List of users will go here'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'category',
                    html : 'List of category will go here'
                }

            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On github Francis Shanahan built a simple sencha touch 2 app in MVC style, if you can follow along with how he defines the views and then uses the alias config to define custom xtypes then it should answer your question. https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld

Answer (score 1):

```
you must have folder structure like that:
 -YourApp
   --app.js // here is your Ext.application
   --app
     --view
       --Users
       --Category
     --model
     --controller
```

Users.js:

```
Ext.define('TheApp.view.Users', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'userspanel',
  config: {
    // here are some config opts...
  }
});
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'TheApp',
  views: [
    'Users',
    'Category'
  ],
  viewport: {
    autoMaximize: true
  },

  launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'userspanel' });
  }
```

Comment: But what if you want your main view to only contain one other view. Some other platforms demand Main as the start of your application. You could have one item with xtype: 'userspanel', but then the elements get crushed making everything look smaller, css does still apply.